# Generic Method to Populate a List Cannot Create T()

Tags: c#, generics, generic-method

I have the generic method below which would serve its purpose if it worked! But the `items.Add(new T(mo));` part wont compile because im using a constructor. Can anyone help?

```
    private List<T> Items<T>(string query) where T : new()
    {

        List<T> items = new List<T>();
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query).Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
            items.Add(new T(mo));

        return items;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `where T : new()` syntax  only allows for *parameterless* constructors. There are some hacks to do this, else `Activator.CreateInstance` should work. But a preferred approach would be an accessible `Init(arg)` method, perhaps via an interface (also specified via `where`). So you can use:

```
var newObj = new T();
newObj.Init(mo);
items.Add(newObj);
```

Comment: Heh, Im feeling sheepish coz that is quite the obvious way to do it :P Thanks!